# LabelBinarizer() Use for csv file

Tags: python

In this code , I did not understand why this function was used and what is its purpose. I read its explanation and searched a lot, but I did not understand. Can you explain in simple terms what he did and why?
https://www.kaggle.com/code/vishwasgpai/guide-for-creating-cnn-model-using-csv-file/notebook

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
y_train = lb.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = lb.fit_transform(y_test)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What _do_ you understand about the [LabelBinarizer() after reading the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) and what specifically is still confusing? Also worth noting: The code you shared in your question shows a common mistake when using encoding. One should always `fit` (or `fit_transform`) on the _training_ data, but only use the _already fitted_ encoder to `transform` the test data